# Create a column of increasing number in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, auto-increment

I want to create a CTE which only contains a single column by Postgresql(Redshift)- increasing number by 1, like 1,2,3,4,..until 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that goes to 1024.  Add "TOP 1000" if you only want 1000.

```
SELECT 
    1 + p0.n
    + p1.n*2
    + p2.n * POWER(2,2)
    + p3.n * POWER(2,3)
    + p4.n * POWER(2,4)
    + p5.n * POWER(2,5)
    + p6.n * POWER(2,6)
    + p7.n * POWER(2,7)
    + p8.n * POWER(2,8)
    + p9.n * POWER(2,9)
    as number
  FROM
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p0,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p1,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p2,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p3,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p4,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p5,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p6,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p7,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p8,
    (SELECT 0 as n UNION SELECT 1) p9
  Order by 1
```

Comment: Oh, that's quite neat.  Self-joins, doubling the number of rows every time.  I use that to populate test tables, never occurred to me to use it as a series generator.  There must be a way to do this with simpler, clearer SQL though.  (Great - yet another thing to figure out :-)

Comment: @MaxGanzII: a recursive CTE could achieve the same https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2d65e3f3e46f3686cfda876cf9eadaae

Comment: Yes.  They are pretty new, though so I've not used them yet.  The question then is which solution is most performant, which is most convenient, and then which is overall the best choice.  Also which is least likely to crash the cluster - Redshift has had problems in the past with recursion.

Comment: BTW, horse, I often see your name editing Redshift questions.  Just curious, what's your history/connection with Redshift?

Comment: @MaxGanzII: none at all, I just remove the Postgres tags for Redshift questions

Comment: The problem with all these in-line approaches is that that are slow AND can create redistribution issues when used with large tables which makes those queries slow.  The better answer when you need a numbers tables on Redshift is (most often) to have a numbers table that is DISTSTYLE ALL.  I read the question as excluding this option which is why I posted my SQL for generating such a numbers table.  With all the discussion I think noting this is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible with a CTE:

```
with recursive numbers (nr) as (
  values (1)
  union all
  select p.nr + 1 
  from numbers p
  where p.nr < 1000
)
select *
from numbers;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2d65e3f3e46f3686cfda876cf9eadaae)

Comment: I've not looked at this closely - just about to go out - am I right to think this is going to call itself 1000 times?